# Singleton object's Spy is calling real method in Junit and Method mocking is not working while running all test together for Mocked object

Tags: java, junit, mockito, singleton, junit5

I have two singleton classes

```java
   public class Singleton1 {

    private static Singleton1 INSTANCE = null;

    private final Singleton2 singleton2;

    private Singleton1(Singleton2 singleton2){
      this.singleton2 = singleton2;
    }

    public static Singleton1 getInstance(Singleton2 singleton2) {
        if(INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton1.class) {
                INSTANCE = new Singleton1(singleton2);
            }
        }
      return INSTANCE;
    }
    
    public String getOutput(String input) {
      switch(input) {
        case "CONNECT" : return "Connected";
        case "PING" : return singleton2.getPingResponse(input);
        default: return "nevermind";
      }
    }

   }
```

Singleton second class

```java
   public class Singleton2 {

    private static Singleton2 INSTANCE = null;
    private Singleton2(){
    }

    public static Singleton2 getInstance() {
        if(INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton1.class) {
                INSTANCE = new Singleton2();
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public  String getPingResponse(String s) {
        System.out.println("CALLING HERE");
        if(s.contains("CON")) {
            return "connected";
        } else {
            return "OK";
        }
     }
   }
```

Test class

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class Singleton1Test { // if running all tests together then the mocking is not happening

    Singleton2 s2 = Mockito.mock(Singleton2.class);
//    Singleton2 s2 = Mockito.mock(Singleton2.class);
//    Singleton2 spiedS2 = Mockito.spy(s2); // if I use spying it will call real method
    Singleton1 s1 = Singleton1.getInstance(s2);

    @Test // this test alone is fine
    public void TestConnect() {
        Assertions.assertEquals("Connected", s1.getOutput("CONNECT"));
    }

    @Test // this test alone is fine
    public void TestPing() {
        // mock will work when I run this test alone
        Mockito.doReturn("OK").when(s2).getPingResponse(anyString());
        // this is calling real method from singleton2 object
//        Mockito.doReturn("OK").when(spiedS2).getPingResponse(anyString());
        Assertions.assertEquals("OK", s1.getOutput("PING"));
    }
}
```

How to do proper JUNIT for singleton1 class, I do not want to execute any method from Singleton2 while running Singleton1. I tried Spying and Mocking. When I am spying the real method is getting called. And When I am mocking Singleton2 all test run failing because of the mock call issue.

If I am wrong somewhere please let me know

Comment: Why are you using `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)`? @RunWith Annotation usually used with JUnit4, but `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` shows that you are using JUnit5.

Comment: Some ids are not yet completely compatible with junit5. Yes I am using junit 5.

Comment: It would be nice to accept an answer according to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Spy is working with instances.

```
 Singleton2 s2 = Singleton2.getInstance();
```

Mock does not need any instance of your Singleton2 to mock It.

I took your code, pimped the test a little bit (start method name with lower case, changed anyString() to ArgumentMatchers.any(String.class)) and tested it. And for me it works fine. I am using Junit 5.7.1 and Mockito 3.8.0. As testing ping method failed for you, I do not insert testing connect in my examples.

I think your error was to mix up Mock and Spy, and not using an instance of Singleton2. let me show you.

I used for examples following imports

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
```

Your code using Mock and Spy Singleton2 (I assume by your comments)

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SingletonTest {

//  Singleton2 s2 = Singleton2.getInstance();
    Singleton2 s2 = Mockito.mock(Singleton2.class);
    Singleton2 spiedS2 = Mockito.spy(s2); // if I use spying it will call real method
    Singleton1 s1 = Singleton1.getInstance(s2);

    @Test // this test alone is fine
    void ping() {
        // mock will work when I run this test alone
        // Mockito.doReturn("OK").when(s2).getPingResponse(any(String.class));
        // this is calling real method from singleton2 object
        Mockito.doReturn("OK").when(spiedS2).getPingResponse(any(String.class));
        Assertions.assertEquals("OK", s1.getOutput("PING"));
    }
}
```

results in

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <OK> but was: <null>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    ...
```

Only use Spy on Singleton2 with instance

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SingletonTest {

    Singleton2 s2 = Singleton2.getInstance();
//  Singleton2 s2 = Mockito.mock(Singleton2.class);
    Singleton2 spiedS2 = Mockito.spy(s2);
    Singleton1 s1 = Singleton1.getInstance(spiedS2);

    @Test // this test alone is fine
    void ping() {
        // Mockito.doReturn("OK").when(s2).getPingResponse(any(String.class));
        Mockito.doReturn("OK").when(spiedS2).getPingResponse(any(String.class));
        Assertions.assertEquals("OK", s1.getOutput("PING"));
    }
}
```

passed the test without failure. Passed also if you use

```
    Singleton1 s1 = Singleton1.getInstance(s2);
```

Only use Mock on Singleton2 without instance

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SingletonTest {

    Singleton2 s2 = Mockito.mock(Singleton2.class);
//  Singleton2 s2 = Singleton2.getInstance();
//  Singleton2 spiedS2 = Mockito.spy(s2);
    Singleton1 s1 = Singleton1.getInstance(s2);

    @Test // this test alone is fine
    void ping() {
        Mockito.doReturn("OK").when(s2).getPingResponse(any(String.class));
        // Mockito.doReturn("OK").when(spiedS2).getPingResponse(any(String.class));
        Assertions.assertEquals("OK", s1.getOutput("PING"));
    }
}
```

also passed the test without failure.

SUPPLEMENT ACCORDING TO SECOND ANSWER

You could define the Mock also by annotations. ( I did not use them previously because example code did not use them.)

```
@Mock
Singleton2 singleton2;

@InjectMocks
Singleton1 s1;
```

Comment: Not worked, it is again calling Singleton 2 real method

Comment: It is working for me when I have only one unit test case in my test class so Yes it will work. But it is failing if I have two test cases. Can you add one more unit test in this test class and run both test cases together.

Comment: i doubled the test case and both tests passed. Show me your second test case.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by the help of two annotations after couple of searches. Now I can run all tests together without error. I renamed the S2 to real S1's property name. So the @InjectMock will work without ambiguity. Mostly the @InjectMock will work by setter or constructor injection. Here my constructor is private but it worked for me.

```java
   @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SingletonTest {

    @Mock
    Singleton2 singleton2;

    @InjectMocks
    Singleton1 s1;

    @Test // this test alone is fine
    public void TestConnect() {
        Assertions.assertEquals("Connected", s1.getOutput("CONNECT"));
    }

    @Test // this test alone is fine
    void ping() {
        Mockito.doReturn("OK").when(singleton2).getPingResponse(anyString());
        Assertions.assertEquals("OK", s1.getOutput("PING"));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is doing the same as `Singleton2 s2 = Mockito.mock(Singleton2.class); Singleton1 s1 = Singleton1.getInstance(s2);` but with annotations.

Comment: Oh okay, In my case Annotation-based mocking worked